# java JFrame height excluding title bar?

Tags: java

when you specify height for JFrame the title bar consumes a part of this height, is there a method or something to know the amount of this consumed part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JFrame` has a method called `getInsets()`

From the Javadoc:

```
getInsets
public Insets getInsets()

Determines the insets of this container, which indicate the size of the container's border. 
A Frame object, for example, has a top inset that corresponds to the height of the frame's title bar.
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't care about the size of the frame itself, instead, allow the content to determine its own size, using the layout management API and then call [`JFrame#pack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) which will wrap the frame around it, taking into account the frames border decorations automatically

Comment: You are probably right in most cases, but that's not to say there aren't valid reasons for wanting to do this.

Comment: @A.Grandt Do what? Wrap the frame around the contents of the view?  *"I'm using `null` layout"* (lets just look past that for a moment), then override `getPreferredSize` and return the size of the area you want to be visible...no need to mess around with the frame's insets :P